# F# adding polynomials recursively

Tags: recursion, f#

I'm trying to write a function in F# that adds polynomials recursively. My polynomials can be represented as a list of tuples.

For example, 2x^4 + 3x^2 + x + 5 is equal to [(2.0,4);(3.0,2);(1.0,1);(5.0,0)]

All polynomials are properly structured (no repeated terms with the same degree, no terms with zero coefficients unless it is the zero polynomial, terms sorted by decreasing exponent no empty input list).

I'm having trouble doing this. Here is my code

```
type term = float * int
type poly = term list

let rec atp(t:term,p:poly):poly =
  match p with
  | [] -> []
  | (a, b) :: tail -> if snd t = b then (fst t + a, b) :: [] elif snd t > b then t :: [] else ([]) :: atp(t, tail)
(* val atp : t:term * p:poly -> poly *)

let rec addpolys(p1:poly,p2:poly):poly =
  match p1 with
  | [] -> []
  | (a,b) :: tail -> atp((a,b), p2) @ addpolys(tail, p2)
```

I have two polynomials

```
val p2 : poly = [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 4); (10.5, 3); (2.25, 2)]
val p1 : poly = [(3.0, 5); (2.0, 2); (7.0, 1); (1.5, 0)]
```

and when I call the function, my result is

```
val p4 : poly =
  [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 5); (3.0, 4); (3.0, 5); (10.5, 3); (3.0, 5); (4.25, 2)]
```

When the correct answer is

```
  [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 5); (3.0, 4); (10.5, 3); (4.25, 2); (7.0, 1); (1.5, 0)]
```

Comment: Your code gives me an error in the FSI: "error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type term but here has type 'a list." Please provide the correct code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your code does not compile therefore it is difficult for me to understand your intentions. But I've got an own implementation for your problem. Maybe it will help you:

```
// addpoly:  (float * 'a) list -> (float * 'a) list -> (float * 'a) list
let rec addpoly p1 p2 =
    match (p1, p2) with
    | [], p2 -> p2
    | p1, [] -> p1
    | (a1, n1)::p1s, (a2, n2)::p2s -> 
        if   n1 < n2 then (a2,    n2) :: addpoly p1  p2s
        elif n1 > n2 then (a1,    n1) :: addpoly p1s p2
        else              (a1+a2, n1) :: addpoly p1s p2s

let p1 = [(3.0, 5); (2.0, 2); ( 7.0, 1);  (1.5, 0)]
let p2 = [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 4); (10.5, 3); (2.25, 2)]

let q = addpoly p1 p2
// val q : (float * int) list =
//   [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 5); (3.0, 4); (10.5, 3); (4.25, 2); (7.0, 1); (1.5, 0)]
```

I would like to make a little note. When you change the representation of the
polynomials a little bit then you can simplify the implementation of your function. You can express a polynomial as a list of its coefficients.

For example when you have this polynomial

```
p1 = 5.0x^5 + 2.0x^2 + 7.0x
```

you can write it also like this

```
p1 = 1.5x^0 + 7.0x^1 + 2.0x^2 + 0.0x^3 + 0.0x^4 + 5.0x^5
```

Therefore you are able to define the polynomial with this list:

```
let p1 = [1.5; 7.0; 2.0; 0.0; 0.0; 5.0]
```

Here are two functions which operates on the representation. polyval calculates the result for a given value and polyadd adds two polynomials. There implementation are rather simple:

```
// p1 = 1.5x^0 + 7.0x^1 + 2.0x^2 + 0.0x^3 + 0.0x^4 + 5.0x^5
let p1 = [1.5; 7.0; 2.0; 0.0; 0.0; 5.0]

// p2 = 0.0x^0 + 0.0x^1 + 2.25x^2 + 10.5x^3 + 3.0x^4 + 0.0x^5 + 0.0x^6 + 4.5x^7
let p2 = [0.0; 0.0; 2.25; 10.5; 3.0; 0.0; 0.0; 4.5]

// polyval: float list -> float -> float
let rec polyval ps x =
    match ps with
    | []    -> 0.0
    | p::ps -> p + x * (polyval ps x)

// polyadd: float int -> float int -> float int
let rec polyadd ps qs =
    match (ps, qs) with
    | [], ys       -> ys
    | xs, []       -> xs
    | x::xs, y::ys -> (x+y)::polyadd xs ys

let v = polyval p1 2.3
// val v : float = 349.99715

let p = polyadd p1 p2
// val p : float list = [1.5; 7.0; 4.25; 10.5; 3.0; 5.0; 0.0; 4.5]
```

Comment: thank you so much, was just wondering how long it took you to write that.. As it took me over 2 hours to write mine and it didn't even work!

Comment: I think it took me no more than 15 minutes but only because I have tried to solve all exercises in "Functional Programming Using F#" so I have a lot of practice. Great book, by the way.

Comment: Be aware that these implementations aren't tail-recursive.

Comment: @mark-seemann: Yes, that is correct. The implementations aren't tail-recursive. But in the context of polynomials this may not be of a great problem unless you would to deal with extremely large ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **completely generic, tail-recursive** implementation:

```
let inline addPolys xs ys =
    let rec imp acc = function
        | (coeffx, degx)::xt, (coeffy, degy)::yt when degx = degy ->
            imp ((coeffx + coeffy, degx)::acc) (xt, yt)
        | (coeffx, degx)::xt, (coeffy, degy)::yt when degx > degy ->
            imp ((coeffx, degx)::acc) (xt, (coeffy, degy)::yt)
        | xs, yh::yt -> imp (yh::acc) (xs, yt)
        | xh::xt, [] -> imp (xh::acc) (xt, [])
        | [], yh::yt -> imp (yh::acc) ([], yt)
        | [], [] -> acc
    imp [] (xs, ys) |> List.rev
```

It has the type:

```
xs:( ^a * 'b) list -> ys:( ^a * 'b) list -> ( ^a * 'b) list
    when  ^a : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a) and 'b : comparison
```

Since `float` has the member `+`, and `int` supports comparison, the type `float * int` matches these generic constraints:

```
> addPolys p1 p2;;
val it : (float * int) list =
  [(4.5, 7); (3.0, 5); (3.0, 4); (10.5, 3); (4.25, 2); (7.0, 1); (1.5, 0)]
```