# Multiplying a list of tuples by a tuple in F#

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I'm writing some code in F# and I need to multiply and add each element in list of tuples `(c,d)` by a tuple `(a,b)`.

To clarify,

- I have some tuple `(a,b)`
- And some list of tuples `[(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)...]`
- and I'm trying to get `[(a*c,b*d),(a*e,b*f),(a*g,b*h)...]`
- and I'm trying to get (with a separate function) `[(a+c,b+d),...]`

I have tried to use `List.map` to multiply each element in the list by a tuple but I get an error that `*` is an invalid operator for type tuple.

This is how I ended up implementing the multiplication function recursively with pattern matching:

```
let rec mtp(t:term,p:poly):poly =
    match (t, p) with
        | (a,b),[] -> []
        | (a, b),(c,d)::ps  -> (a*c,b*d)::mtp(t,ps)
```

Where term is a tuple of float * int and poly is a list of terms

Comment: At least show what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: At SO it is expected that you show what you have tried so that 1. We are not doing your homework for you. 2. So that we can see if you have a simple mistake easily corrected. 3. So that others who probably have the same idea as you will know if they have the same idea as you. Because you did not give an attempt, most of us will not give you an answer. Also you need to look for an answer in SO as a similar one was just given in the previous days, e.g. [F# adding polynomials recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35376734/1243762)

Comment: @GuyCoder thank you, I'm actually having trouble where to start! The link you provided for me helped a lot! Thank you

Comment: No need to be that hostile to a newbie (who even seem to provide his real name) - the F# community used to be one of the friendlier around SO and wouldn't it be great if we would welcome new members? After all it's not like F# is mainstream or something ...

Comment: @Carsten Who is being hostile. If you mean the person who gave the down vote and close vote it was not me.

Comment: @GuyCoder and I did not mention you in the comment ;) - indeed your comment **is** helpful (as the OP mentioned as well)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question as far as I can see! Matthew - I think people would be happier if they saw your attempt (the version that gave you the error you mentioned), even if it was quite simple and it didn't quite work. Sometimes people on StackOverflow are upset when they see questions with no code... I also edited your question so that it does not contain "Thank you" and the introduction (and I fixed some formatting). StackOverflow tries to be "pure Q&A" - so a better way to thank to @GuyCoder is in a comment. And finally, welcome! :-)

Comment: Hopefully anything I said was not taken wrong. If it was, then I'm sorry. There are a lot of new people here lately and from the consistency of the questions they are in a course together. That's great, but odds are if one of them has a problem, then so do the others. By those posting the question showing their work, then if their classmates have the same problem they might realize it is not them as an individual, because several of them had them had the same problem.

Comment: totally OT but is there a F# course somewhere (**great!!**) is it online? - the last thing I've seen was this horrible F# MOOC (~cannot even remember on what platform~ ... edX by Microsoft :( ) where they started days late and the stuff was so bad that I did dropped after the second week - gladly the Ocaml MOOC started soon after and I would recommend this to people wanting to learn F# atm

Comment: Because of all of the similar questions I did some Googling and found [02157 Functional Programming](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02157/2012/) I don't know if it is the course they are doing, but a lot of the problems there are showing up consistently here by at least four people for sure and maybe as high as seven. See [plan](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02157/2012/plan.html) for the assignments

Comment: hey cool - the book it's based on is rather good IMO

Comment: @Carsten The course is taught by one of the authors of that book :-)

Comment: @MY_G I suspected as much ;) ... but isn't it great that F# is now taught for FP courses at least in one instance? The save bet usually was Scheme/Lisp/Racket, Haskell or (Oc)aml

Comment: @Carsten It is indeed really great :-)

Comment: FYI, Phan Anh Dung AKA [Pad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/634025/pad) was a teaching assistant for the course. I haven't seen him active here for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok `List.map` is a good idea - you only have to make sure that you provide something (let's say a lambda) to tell F# how to operate on two tuples.

To make it a bit more general you could do something like this:

```
let withTuple (a,b) op tpls = 
   List.map (fun (a',b') -> (op a a', op b b')) tpls
```

And work with it as you expected

```
> withTuple (1,1) (+) [(2,3);(4,5)];;
val it : (int * int) list = [(3, 4); (5, 6)]
> withTuple (2,1) (*) [(2,3);(4,5)];; 
val it : (int * int) list = [(4, 3); (8, 5)]
```

---

to understand it a bit better you should:

- try to figure out the signature (well use F#/F# Interactive if you like)
- maybe try to write a function where the parts of the tuple can have different types (**hint**: you need more than one `op` function)
- why do you need more than one function for the last one? (why will `withTuple (2.0,1) (*) [(2.1,3);(4.2,5)]` not work - isn't `(+)` supposed to work for all numbers?)

Comment: Thank you this really helps!

Comment: just make sure you understand it! - For example I did not *add* the last parameter to `List.map` - do you know why this works?

Comment: I'm playing around with the code in interactive right now @Carsten

Comment: @Matthew Carsten gives great answers and will help you if you need it. Make sure you fully understand his solution before you accept it as an answer. By accepting it as an answer we take it that you need no more help; but if you don't accept an answer, then post a comment explaining why and asking questions. We also learn from helping others, so it is a two way street. Also you can upvote an answer and then wait a few days to accept an answer, this is common practice.

Comment: @Carsten Assuming to answer your third point would be because F# dynamically assigns a type to the * operator and it wouldn't allow a float * int?

Comment: well in this case it would try to use it with `int*int -> int` for the first component of the pairs and with `float*float->float` for the second component - this is why this will not work as the type of `op` will be some `'a*'a->'a` (saying: *yes it can be generic*  but it must have **some** type `'a`) but here it is used with two different types

Comment: @Carsten I still don't understand how you can add the list [(2,3);(4,5)] to the function without it being declared

Comment: ah ok - understandable (indeed I should not have done this and I'll fix it) - I only partially applied `List.map` so the *result* is a function ;)

Comment: you can see the last point in (the somewhat scary) signature of `withTuple`: `a:'a * b:'a -> op:('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> (('b * 'b) list -> ('c * 'c) list)` - `('b * 'b) list -> ('c * 'c) list` will be the result and this is yet again a function

Comment: if I add the parameter `tpls` as I now did it will be: `a:'a * b:'a -> op:('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> tpls:('b * 'b) list -> ('c * 'c) list` which really is the same (minus the now named parameter and the missing `(...)` pair ... but you should always think `'a -> 'b -> 'c = 'a -> ('b -> 'c)`)

Comment: @Carsten Thank you so much I understand now. Going to try to implement something similar for my code without copying.